# Mongoose: Aggregating and Counting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a NodeJS/MongoDB app which has data stored in a collection called `"Feedback"`. The data looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "__v": 0,
        "_id": "57d6b2d09f46ca14440ac14e",
        "customerFeedback": [
            {
                "_id": "57d6b2d09f46ca14440ac14f",
                "answer": [
                    {
                        "_id": "57d6b2d09f46ca14440ac150",
                        "answerValue": "cat",
                        "answerWeight": 0
                    }
                ],
                "question": "What is your favourite thing about this shop?",
                "questionId": "57d65edc0132461120fa0afd"
            },
            {
                "_id": "57d6b2d09f46ca14440ac151",
                "answer": [
                    {
                        "_id": "57d6b2d09f46ca14440ac152",
                        "answerValue": "Okay",
                        "answerWeight": 0
                    }
                ],
                "question": "How was your experience today?",
                "questionId": "57d69ef6dbb25611e46e6bc9"
            }
        ],
        "shopId": "SH0001",
        "feedbackCreatedOn": "2016-09-12T13:51:12.703Z",
        "questionsForDay": "2016-09-12T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "__v": 0,
        "_id": "57d6b3389f46ca14440ac157",
        "customerFeedback": [
            {
                "_id": "57d6b3389f46ca14440ac158",
                "answer": [
                    {
                        "_id": "57d6b3389f46ca14440ac159",
                        "answerValue": "cat",
                        "answerWeight": 0
                    }
                ],
                "question": "What is your favourite thing about this shop?",
                "questionId": "57d65edc0132461120fa0afd"
            },
            {
                "_id": "57d6b3389f46ca14440ac15a",
                "answer": [
                    {
                        "_id": "57d6b3389f46ca14440ac15b",
                        "answerValue": "Very Good",
                        "answerWeight": 0
                    }
                ],
                "question": "How was your experience today?",
                "questionId": "57d69ef6dbb25611e46e6bc9"
            },
            {
                "_id": "57d6b3389f46ca14440ac15c",
                "answer": [
                    {
                        "_id": "57d6b3389f46ca14440ac15d",
                        "answerValue": "Cost",
                        "answerWeight": 0
                    }
                ],
                "question": "What would you like us to improve on?",
                "questionId": "57d6b32d9f46ca14440ac153"
            }
        ],
        "shopId": "SH0001",
        "feedbackCreatedOn": "2016-09-12T13:52:56.939Z",
        "questionsForDay": "2016-09-12T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "__v": 0,
        "_id": "57d6c8eb97157f10a4e5c2e7",
        "customerFeedback": [
            {
                "_id": "57d6c8eb97157f10a4e5c2e8",
                "answer": [
                    {
                        "_id": "57d6c8eb97157f10a4e5c2ea",
                        "answerValue": "Customer Experience",
                        "answerWeight": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "57d6c8eb97157f10a4e5c2e9",
                        "answerValue": "Others",
                        "answerWeight": 0
                    }
                ],
                "question": "What would you like us to improve on?",
                "questionId": "57d6b7d99ee61e47f01e5334"
            }
        ],
        "shopId": "SH0003",
        "feedbackCreatedOn": "2016-09-12T15:25:31.724Z",
        "questionsForDay": "2016-09-12T00:00:00Z"
    }
]
```

There are many such entries in the array of results, but the above data serves to illustrate it.

My question is, for a given `shopId` and `questionId`, I want to count the number of times each individual `answerValue` occurs. How do I do it?

I am able to filter the results down to the required datasets using the find method as (for example)

```
db.Feedback.find({shopId:"SH0001",'customerFeedback.questionId':"57d65edc0132461120fa0afd"})
```

But I'm not sure how to aggregate the data to the format I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pipeline should give you the desired result

```
db.getCollection("yourCollection").aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$customerFeedback" },
    { $unwind: "$customerFeedback.answer" },
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: {
                shopId: "$shopId",
                questionId: "$customerFeedback.questionId",
                answerValue: "$customerFeedback.answer.answerValue"
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

which for your sample data gives the following output

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "shopId" : "SH0003",
        "questionId" : "57d6b7d99ee61e47f01e5334",
        "answerValue" : "Others"
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "shopId" : "SH0003",
        "questionId" : "57d6b7d99ee61e47f01e5334",
        "answerValue" : "Customer Experience"
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "shopId" : "SH0001",
        "questionId" : "57d65edc0132461120fa0afd",
        "answerValue" : "cat"
    },
    "count" : 2.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "shopId" : "SH0001",
        "questionId" : "57d69ef6dbb25611e46e6bc9",
        "answerValue" : "Okay"
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "shopId" : "SH0001",
        "questionId" : "57d6b32d9f46ca14440ac153",
        "answerValue" : "Cost"
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "shopId" : "SH0001",
        "questionId" : "57d69ef6dbb25611e46e6bc9",
        "answerValue" : "Very Good"
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}
```

Of course you can filter the result down with an additional [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage if you are just interested in specific values

---

Update due to comment:

To filter your result down with `$match` you could use it after unwinding the nested array of customer feedbacks like so

```
...
{ $unwind: "$customerFeedback" },
{ $match: { shopId: "SH0001", "customerFeedback.questionId": "57d65edc0132461120fa0afd" } },
{ $unwind: "$customerFeedback.answer" },
{ 
    $group: {
        _id: {
            shopId: "$shopId",
            questionId: "$customerFeedback.questionId",
            answerValue: "$customerFeedback.answer.answerValue"
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}
...
```

which would result in

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "shopId" : "SH0001",
        "questionId" : "57d65edc0132461120fa0afd",
        "answerValue" : "cat"
    },
    "count" : 2.0
}
```

If you have a large number of documents or an index on `shopId` and / or `customerFeedback.questionId` then you might want to duplicate that `$match` stage to the front of your pipeline so that you unwind only the documents of the corresponding shop and with at least one feedback of the desired question. So with that (optional optimization from the correctness point of view) it would look like so

```
...
{ $match: { shopId: "SH0001", "customerFeedback.questionId": "57d65edc0132461120fa0afd" } },
{ $unwind: "$customerFeedback" },
{ $match: { shopId: "SH0001", "customerFeedback.questionId": "57d65edc0132461120fa0afd" } },
{ $unwind: "$customerFeedback.answer" },
{ 
    $group: {
        _id: {
            shopId: "$shopId",
            questionId: "$customerFeedback.questionId",
            answerValue: "$customerFeedback.answer.answerValue"
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for your reply. I want to filter down the result by questionId. Where in the pipeline should I add the $match clause? I tried doing it, but I was not very successful. The questionId is nested inside CustomerFeedback and that stumps me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am able to get it working in the DB shell. However I'm facing difficulties using that in my app. I've updated my question to explain.

Comment: Is there a different way you want your results displayed?

Comment: @dyouberg The output format which DAXaholic suggested is good enough. If you notice his sample results, it'll have all questionIds listed. I simply want to filter it down, which somehow is not working for me in Mongoose. (I can do it manually in Mongo Shell)

Comment: @DAXaholic Nevermind. I got it working. The mistake was on my part. Your solutions works perfectly! Thanks a lot! :)